# Unable to install magento 2.2 on windows 10, missing commands

Tags: php, magento2

For two days I am trying to install magento version 2.2 on windows 10 operational system. I am cloning existing project from online repository. When everything is done and when I try to run application, magento commands in CLI are missing. I need to set mode to production but it is impossible as all deploy commands are missing. Below is example in CLI what happens:

```
$ bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]   There
>   are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.

This is happening for few more commands. And also in list of commands in CLI missing commands are not listed.

Tried to reinstall project, different version of project, reinstall composer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the generated dependency injection classes are not working correctly.
Try removing the generated files

```
del /S /F var/di
rmdir var/di
```

and regenerate classes:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Afterwards you should be able to use the CLI Commands

Comment: You mentioned you have cloned the repository.

Can you explain what you did? ("When everything was done" doesn't really say what you have done)

Did you run `composer install` after you cloned it?

Did you import a database dump from another server?

Did you make sure the database credentials in app/etc/env.php are correct?

Comment: Yes I have done everything, database imported, composer install run, env file everything is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to my problem:**

setup:install command didn't completed untill the end, there is error in Installer.php file inside /setup/../Installer.php